# How to call a php web service from a java application without any external dependancies?

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws

I have created a very simple php web service, which is not having the WSDL. I find a way to call it from the java application.

```
String endpoint = "http://localhost/webser/simple_server.php";  
            Service service = new Service();
            Call call = (Call) service.createCall();
            call.setTargetEndpointAddress( new java.net.URL(endpoint) );
            call.setOperationName( new QName("urn://tyler/req") );
            String ret=(String)call.invoke("readfat",new Object[]{});
            System.out.print(ret);
```

It works fine and gives the output. But it need external jar files like **axis1-3.jar,commons-discovery, commons-logging**.....etc. I want to know whether there is a way to consume a web service without any external dependancies?. My actual need is to consume the web service from an **Applet**. So I cannot tolerate the external depepndancies. can JAX-WS be used for this purpose?

Comment: You can use HttpUrlConnection like explained in this post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/how-to-use-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests.

Comment: Thank you gerrytan.... Its a useful Link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to call a web service if you can simply make the HTTP requests yourself.

If you don't want any external dependencies the class to use from the standard library is [`java.net.HttpURLConnection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html).

[This question has a very detailed answer showing you how to do this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/how-to-use-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests)

Comment: WOW!! Thank You! You made it so simple. I have thinked a lot. But if I add a few lines in my WS.php, using java.net.HttpURLConnection, it will work like charm. Its a wise answer Dave and gerrytan